# 1020px Grid System Problems HTML

Tags: html, css, web, grid, sass

Hi I am trying to create a grid system in HTML with max width of 1020px.

I have the following CSS:

```
* {
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}

$pad: 20px;

.container_20 {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 0 $pad 0;
  width: 1020px;

  &:after {
    /* Or @extend clearfix */
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  padding-right: $pad;
  .grid &:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.col-1-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-1-4 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-1-8 {
  width: 12.5%;
}

.module {
  padding: $pad;
  background: #eee;
}

/* Opt-in outside padding */
.grid-pad {
  padding: $pad 0 $pad $pad;
  [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
    padding-right: $pad;
  }
}

}
```

But whenever I try to implement it in the HTML I do not get the desired effect. Would anyone be able to help me out as to what the correct code should be to get a grid and be able to align items correctly, side by side, in halves and thirds?

EDIT: HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>TreeScapes Northern Ireland</title>
        <meta name="TreeScapes NI" content="TreeScapes, Tree, NI">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon(s) in the root directory -->


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

        <!-- Chris Rolston Web Design - Engage IT -->

        <header class="container_20">
            <h1> TreeScapes </h1>
            <nav id="cssmenu" class="container_20">
                <ul>
                    <li class='active'>
                        <a href="#"><span>HOME</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span>ABOUT US</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span>SERVICES</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span>NEWS</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span>ASK THE EXPERT</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span>ARRANGE A CALLBACK</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span>CONTACT US</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/tree_twitter.gif" alt="Contact us on Twitter">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/tree_facebook.gif" alt="Contact us on Facebook">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>



        <div id="main" class="container_20">

<p>

        Space for Slideshow Insert upon WordPress Convert

        <p>

        <img src="img/tree_divide.png">


            <div id="service_1" class="col-1-3">
                <h3> SERVICE 1 </h3>
            </div>
                <div id="service_2" class="col-1-3">
                <h3> SERVICE 2 </h3>
            </div>
                <div id="service_3" class="col-1-3">
                <h3> SERVICE 3 </h3>
            </div>

        <div id="primary" class="col-1-2">
        <h1> Tree Surgeons Belfast </h1>
        <article class="col-1-2">
            <h2>
                Welcome to TreeScapes, <br>Expert Tree Surgeons <br>Belfast and Northern Ireland
            <img src="img/tree_log.gif">


            <h6> 
                When looking for tree surgeons in Belfast and Northern Ireland TreeScapes NI is one of the leading arboricultural companies in the province. Our focus is on delivering a professional and high quality <a href="#"> tree surgery </a> service with excellent and responsive customer care. 
                <br>
                ..........................
                <p>
                Our tree surgeons provide a tree management and contracting service to both the private and commerical market. Clients include organisations such as local authorities, utility companies, civil engineering companies, housing associations, colleges, schools and churches. Increasingly we work on the basis of developing long-term partnerships with our clients. 

            </h2>




            <aside class="col-1-4">
                <div id="twitter_feed">
                <img src="img/tree_twitter_bg.gif">
            </div>

            <div id="expert" class="col-1-8">
                <img src="img/tree_logcut">
                Ask the expert
            </div>
            <aside>
                <div id="Insured" class="col-1-8">
                    <img src="img/tree_leaf.gif">
                    <h3> Fully insured </h3>
                    <h6> * £10 MILLION PUBLIC LIABILITY * <h6>



            </aside> 

        </aside>

    <div id="contact" class="col-1-2">
        <article>
            <h6> 
                IF you are in need of our professional tree surgeons in 
                Belfast or the surrounding Northern Ireland area please:
                <p>
                    CONTACT US TODAY CLICK HERE
            </h6>

            <img src="img/tree_divide.png">
        <p>
    </div>

</div>

    <div id="footer" class="container_20">
        <div id="contact_foot" class="col-1-2">
            <div id="bottom" class="flot-bottom">
        <h6>
            Tel: 028 90705161 - Mob: 0773818 174 - Freephone: 08000 699 738 <br> Email: info@treescapeni.co.uk - Copyright: Treescapes NI - Skype: Treescapes
            <p>

            <div id="footernav" class="col-1-2">
                <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">SITE MAP</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">TERMS AND CONDITIONS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
        </h6>

        <div id="city" class="col-1-8">
            <img href="img/tree_review_footer.gif">
            <img href="img/tree_cityg_footer.gif">

    </div>
</div>














        <!-- Chris Rolston Web Design - Engage IT -->


    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you applying a `max-width` and how are you floating the elements?

Comment: There is nothing problematic in the code you've shown. Please post the HTML that reproduces the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not pure CSS. You are using SASS (which must be compiled first).

Try the compiled CSS version:

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.grid [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-1-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-1-4 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-1-8 {
  width: 12.5%;
}

.module {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}

/* Opt-in outside padding */
.grid-pad {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
}
.grid-pad [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this its helped me out a lot. Although the max width is not staying at the desired 1020px. How could I sort this out?

Comment: Can you post the HTML with classes?

Comment: I changed the css to say 'container_20' where it said grid

Comment: Use as follows:
`<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-2-3">
     Here comes 2/3 sized content
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-3">
     Here comes 1/3 sized content
  </div>
</div>`

don't rename the classes for simplicity.

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you for the help. The only problem that still remains is the max width not being 1020px. Im not sure if I have this coded correctly in my css. What do you think? The max width is currently around 1500px and I do not know why.

Comment: I think the problem is that your classes add up to more than the desired width. Next is that your HTML Tags are not closed properly, for example the `<article>` that has a `col-1-2`.

Maybe you should find a HTML Editor that helps you to close the tags correctly. I recommend Brackets.io or SublimeText.